# Downloading torrent file using get request (.torrent)

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, python-requests

I am trying to download torrent file from this code :

```
url = "https://itorrents.org/torrent/0BB4C10F777A15409A351E58F6BF37E8FFF53CDB.torrent"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('test123.torrent', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

It downloads a torrent file , but when i load it to bittorrent error occurs.

It says **Unable to Load , Torrent Is Not Valid Bencoding**

Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem  ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bypassing Cloudflare can be a pain, so I suggest using a library that handles it. Please don't forget that your code may break in the future because Cloudflare changes their techniques periodically. Well, if you use the library, you will just need to update the library (at least you should hope for that).

I used a similar library only in NodeJS, but I see python also has something like that - [cloudscraper](https://github.com/venomous/cloudscraper)

Example:

```py
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
print scraper.get("http://somesite.com").text  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

Depending on your usage you may need to consider using proxies - CloudFlare can still block you if you send too many requests.

---

Also, if you are working with **video torrents**, you may be interested in [Torrent Stream Server](https://github.com/KiraLT/torrent-stream-server). It a server that downloads and streams video at the same time, so you can **watch the video without fully downloading it**.

Answer (score 1):

This page use `cloudflare` to prevent scraping the page,I am sorry to say that bypassing `cloudflare` is very hard if you only use `requests`, the measures `cloudflare` takes will update soon.This page will check your browser whether it support `Javascript`.If not, they won't give you the bytes of the file.That's why you couldn't use them.(You could use `r.text` to see the response content, it is a html page.Not a file.)

Under this circumstance, I think you should consider about using `selenium`.

Comment: other choices use proxies, vpn, or services such as scraperapi.com , i prefer to use scraperapi because they are taking care of bypassing them very good .

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i let the browser to open link directly without using get request

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R What do you mean?If you enter this page in browser, browser would send GET requests to this page.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i mean i put this code `webbrowser.open_new_tab(Down_link)`

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R That's also okay.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i sent get request with headers and it worked . but because of the cookie changes time ti time . it fails when cookie expires

Answer (score 0):

We can do by adding cookies in headers .
But after some time cookie expires.
Therefore only solution is to download from opening browser